# jquery $(this).find not working for me

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

okay so in php tags i have this:

```
<?php
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li id='lis'> WELCOME ".$_SESSION['username']."!<ul><li><a href='#'>link1</a></li></ul></li>";
echo "<ul>";
?>
```

i am trying to make it so it will show the link1 on hover. so i am using jquery and my code for that is:

```
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul>li').fadeToggle(400);
    });
});
```

i have no idea what to do to fix this, please help! if you have any suggestions on how to fix the code please leave them down below i would really appreciate it.

here is the whole thing:

```
            <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <style type="text/css">
            ul{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            list-style: none;
            float: right;
        }
        ul li{
            float: left;
            width: 150px;
            height: 30px;
            line-height: 30px;
        }
        ul li a{
            background-color: cyan;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        ul li li {
            color:#fff;
            display: none;
        }

        ul li{
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .top{
            position: static;
            right: 0;
            top: 0px;
        }

            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript"src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('li').hover(function(){
                    $(this).find('ul>li').fadeToggle(400);
                });
            });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <?php
            echo "<ul>";
            echo "<li id='lis'> WELCOME ".$_SESSION['username']."!<ul><li><a href='#'>hello</a></li></ul></li>";
            echo "<ul>";
        ?>
        </body>
        </html>
```

that is named welcome.php
i have another file named index.php where i include that into my php.

Comment: Using just this in the console works for me: `$('li#lis').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('ul>li').fadeToggle(400);
    });` Note however that I used the `id` of the `li` ... your `$('li').hover(...)` selector is going to get _every_ `li` on the page. Note also this can be done with ***no*** javascript by using a `:hover` selector and CSS3 transitions.

Answer (score 1):

hide your `li` containing the link, then toggle it .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#lis').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul>li').fadeToggle(400);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id='lis'>WELCOME ".$_SESSION['username']."!
    <ul>
      <li style="display:none;"><a href='#'>link1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @garrett glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Add a class that hides the link on render.

Then target the `a` and toggle that.

In your case it would not work if you hide the `li` as there is no element to hover if you hide the `li`

**JS**

```
$('li').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('ul > li > a').fadeToggle(400);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href='#' class="hide">link1</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hgob6ta7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Because your `$('li')` select ALL `<li>`s in the document, include the `<li><a href='#'>link1</a></li>`, try to use `#id` selector instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#lis').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul>li').fadeToggle(400);
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if it selects all `li`s. It will still find `ul > li` of a `li` that does have those descendants.